# How to use a Bootstrap popover in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap popover on my HTML page.  
I have a popup that is in an HTML table which I am building dynamically and I suspect I am not registering the event correctly.

My HTML:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, elem) {                 
    var radioBtn = "<input type='radio' name='radOption' class='radio selectedOptionAdd' data-value='myData' />";     
    var popupContent = "TO DO MAKE A TABLE OF DATA";
    var popupControl = "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-danger permissionPopUpButton' role='button' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='focus' title='Dismissible popover' data-content='" + popupContent + "'>Dismissible popover</a>";
    myTable += "<tr><td>" + radioBtn + "</td><td>" + popupControl  + "</td></tr>";
});
```

In my document.ready I have the following statement:

```
// Originally tried this but this doesn't work
//$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$("body").on("click", ".permissionPopUpButton", function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

Any advice on how to correctly register this event?

Comment: FYI - I am using Bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: Try to register event after you load DOM with dynamic elements, instead of in document.ready. When you register in document.ready event it expects those elements to be present in DOM.

Comment: You should do it after you finish building dynamic table. If you can, please post jsfiddle link so that I can update it.

Comment: jsfiddle is locked down here.   I did try moving my code after the table was created and it still didnt work.  I also tried     $('body').popover({
        trigger: "click",
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        selector: '[rel=popover]'
    });

Comment: Where do you have rel=popover attribute on button? Please go through, http://jsbin.com/zopod/1/edit?html,css,js. I think problem is its not able to find elements using selector.

Comment: I'l check your link when I get home.  That url is blocked for me.  I'll also double check my attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this will work.

```
$("body").on("click", ".permissionPopUpButton", function () {
    $(".popover").css("width", "276px");
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();        
});
```

However I was missing the "tabindex='0'.  Once I added that to my tag the popup started working!

```
var popupControl = "<a tabindex='0' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger permissionPopUpButton' role='button' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='focus' title='I am a title' data-content='I AM CONTENT HEAR ME ROAR'>Dismissible popover</a>";
```